# Opening static html page discovered from Web.API controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web.API service running at '`http://mywebserver/report`' where in my controller I check to search for the existence of a static html file on the server like this:

```
bool exists = File.Exists( Path.Combine( HostingEnvironment.MapPath( @"\atlas" ), "report.html") );
```

This works fine, and finds my file okay- 'atlas' is the virtual directory path, so I should be able to open '`http://mywebserver/atlas/report.html`'.  The problem is that when I return the bool that the file exists to the client and can be opened, if I try to open the file from my jQuery it places it in the originating URL, and tries to open '`http://mywebserver/report/report.html`', which doesn't work.

In IIS, I can't map the virtual directory and the application directory to the same location... and I don't want to hard code in my full web service URL on the client, like window.open("`http://mywebserver/atlas/`" + "report.html").

Is there some way to work around this?  Maybe a way to have my controller push the correct URL back to the client to open?  How do I get the URL mapping to the virtual directory?  I think I'm doing this the hard way... I just want that if the file is found it gets opened in a new window....

Comment: What do you mean by "opened in a new window"? What's the sequence of events here? A user visits `http://mywebserver/report` and then `report.html` opens in a *new* window? Or they visit `http://mywebserver/report` and are *immediately* shown the content of report.html? Or... redirected to report.html?

Comment: A user visits `http://mywebserver/report` and does a search for a existing report.  If it exists, the report opens in a new window where the url should be `http://mywebserver/atlas/report.html`.

Comment: Returning the URL for the report makes sense. If the report doesn't exist, an empty string could indicate "false".

Comment: Yep that seems like the way to go... is there a simple way to get the root url of my site from the controller?  The `http://mywebserver/` address, not the `http://mywebserver/report` url.. I'll see if I can find it..